# LeetCode - Why does this function return undefined, although it has just logged an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, undefined

As I'm new to programming, I'm currently trying to apply the basics I learnt by solving some simple problems on LeetCode. However the problem "3Sum" has led me to something I just don't seem to understand. 
Here is the definition of the exercise:

> Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Now, here is what I've come up with yet:

```
var result = [];
var threeSum = function(nums) {
    for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[0] + nums[i] + nums[j] == 0) {
                result.push([nums[0], nums[i], nums[j]])
            }
        }
    }

    if(nums.length > 3) {
        nums.shift();
        threeSum(nums);
    } else {
        console.log("result: ", result);
        return result;
    } 
};
```

Now I was testing this with the following input:

> [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]

The console.log statement in the else block at the bottom gave:

> result:  [ [ -1, 0, 1 ], [ -1, 2, -1 ], [ 0, 1, -1 ] ]

which is exactly what I've wanted it to log out for now.

However the return statement below returns "undefined".

As they are both in the same else block, I think they should both be executed.
How can "result" be logged as an Array, however returning it causes it to be "undefined"?

Please note that I'm aware this might not be the correct way to solve this problem, nor this is solution is sufficient for the exercise. I'm not asking for any correction, as I want to develop the algorithm by myself, it's just the fact that, in this case, "result" seems to be defined and undefined at the same time :)

Comment: You're missing the `return` in the recursive call

Comment: BTW, a recursive function should generally invoke itself using a name given _after_ the `function` keyword rather than one that happens to have been assigned to a `var` in the enclosing scope.    If something overrides the latter your recursion breaks, but a named function's name is always valid within the scope of that function.

Comment: @Alnitak Oh, I see that makes sense. I usually don't write function as in the example above, that was already pre-written by LeetCode when I started that exercise. But anyways, good to know thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add the return in order to do your recursion:

```js
var result = [];
var threeSum = function(nums) {
    for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[0] + nums[i] + nums[j] == 0) {
                result.push([nums[0], nums[i], nums[j]])
            }
        }
    }

    if(nums.length > 3) {
        nums.shift();
        return threeSum(nums);  // <-- return here
    } else {
        return result;
    } 
};

console.log(threeSum([-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has answered my problem! In fact, seeing this, it makes really sense, however I don't fully understand, why it does not work without the return...